# How to apply the intersection between two lists in C++?

Tags: c++, list

I am new to C++ *list*.

I have two lists: `list1` and `list2`. I need to get common elements between these lists. How can I get this?

Comment: What if the lists *themselves* contain duplicates?

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One way is to follow the example given here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection.

Comment: @Bathsheba: The usual definition means that `intersection(A,A)=A`. Obviously, this precludes the removal of duplicates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use: [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) for that, provided you first sort the two lists:

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> list1{2, 5, 7, 8, -3, 7};
    std::list<int> list2{9, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 11, 0};

    list1.sort();
    list2.sort();

    std::list<int> out;
    std::set_intersection(list1.begin(), list1.end(), list2.begin(), list2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(out));

     for(auto k : out)
         std::cout << k << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
2 5
```

**EDIT:**

The above method is likely not going to be optimal, mostly because sorting a **`std::list`** isn't nice to the CPU...

For a trade-off of space, the method below will certainly be faster for larger sets of data, because we iterate through each list only once, and all operations done at each iteration doesn't go beyond a `O(1)` amortized complexity

```
template<typename T>
std::list<T> intersection_of(const std::list<T>& a, const std::list<T>& b){
    std::list<T> rtn;
    std::unordered_multiset<T> st;
    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [&st](const T& k){ st.insert(k); });
    std::for_each(b.begin(), b.end(),
        [&st, &rtn](const T& k){
            auto iter = st.find(k);
            if(iter != st.end()){
                rtn.push_back(k);
                st.erase(iter);
            }
        }
    );
    return rtn;
}
```

*I used `std::unordered_multiset` rather than `std::unordered_set` because it preserves the occurences of common duplicates in both lists*

I ran a [dirty benchmark](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a2abcd9bc4a02e4) for the two methods on randomly generated `9000` `int`s, The result was (lower is better):

```
Average timings for 100 runs:
intersection_of:  8.16 ms
sortAndIntersect: 18.38 ms
```

---

Analysis of using the `std::set_intersection` method:

- Sorting *List 1* of size `N` is: `O(Nlog(N))`
- Sorting *List 2* of size `M` is: `O(Mlog(M))`
- Finding the Intersection is: `O(M + N)`
- Total: `O( Nlog(N) + Mlog(M) + M + N)` ...(generalized as logarithmic)

Assuming `M` and `N` are equal, we can generalize it as: `O(Nlog(N))`

But if we use the `intersection_of` method I posted above:

- Iterating through *List 1* of size `N` and adding to the set is: `O(N) + O(1) = O(N)`
- Iterating through *List 2* of size `M`, checking the *multiset*, adding to *`out`*, removing from *List 2* : `O(M) + O(1) + O(1) + O(1)` = `O(M)`
- Total: `O(M + N)` ...(generalized as linear)

Assuming `M` and `N` are equal, we can generalize it as: `O(N)`

Comment: Saw you reversed my edit: note there is no such function `std::intersection` in standard C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba, Thanks, I was editing the answer. THe reversal was a mistake

Comment: What is the necessity of using unordered_multiset ? Why do we need to keep the duplicates since the result would be different if we exchange the order of a and b?